# Comparing comma separated numbers in cells

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am trying to compare the numbers in the `Reachability Set` column with the numbers in the same row of the `Antecedent Set` column  and return the common values in the corresponding cells of the `Intersection Set` column.

***Screenshot:***
[image]

Comment: What's the question ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: You need `VBA` code to achieve that. So first google search to learn vba, then try some code by yourself and post here the codes you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel 2016 (but NOT Excel 2013), you can use the following **array-entered** formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(1/(1/(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))&",",","&A2&","))))*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),""))
```

**seq_99** is a **Named Formula**

```
Refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

To enter an array formula, after entering the formula in the cell, confirm by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do it correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: I am stunned after seeing this answer, I was struggling to find a way for the past 6hrs. Mind Blowing Logic

Comment: @RanjithRaj Thank you. Unfortunately, not possible without helper columns prior to the `TEXTJOIN` function in 2016.

Comment: I dont get the result, can you send me tat excel file

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score -1):

Although you would think a VBA solution is required, it is actually quite simple to do this with formulae, provided you use a *lot* of helper columns. These can, of course, be hidden.

All you need is a number of columns equivalent to the maximum of the numerals in the sets, after *each* of the original columns of your table. For the example supplied, this would be 17 columns.

Here is a screenshot of the new table with the helper columns unhidden:

[image: screenshot of new table]

The follow formulae are entered into the top left cell of each coloured region and filled/copy-pasted/ctrl-entered into the rest of the cells.

Red Cells (entered into `B2`):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(","&B$1&",",","&$A2&",")),0,1)
```

Green Cells (entered into `T2`):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(","&T$1&",",","&$S2&",")),0,1)
```

Blue Cells (entered into `AL2`):

```
=IF(B2*T2,AL$1&",","")&AM2
```

And finally, the result entered into cell `AK`:

```
=LEFT(AL2,LEN(AL2)-1)
```

The formulae work by ensuring that all the numbers in the sets have a preceding, and trailing, comma so that they can be uniquely searched for.

Then it is a simple matter of constructing a grid for the sets where a `1` means the number exists in the set a `0`  means it doesn't. Multiplying these two grids together results in the "intersection set".

Then it is a simple matter of reconstituting the result strings.

---

**Caveat:**

This solution won't work correctly if there are any spaces in the "Set" data. To overcome this you need to use the `SUBSTITUTE()` function.

Comment: Thanks man, tat was very useful. ur have good logical thinking