# Comparing comma separated alphanumeric characters in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229507/comparing-comma-separated-numbers-in-cells/64428251#64428251)

Please refer to the original question above. I was told to ask a new question.

Ron Rosenfeld's solution works great on numbers but how would the formula change if my two lists are alphanumeric e.g. P1234,C4321,P0123,P0678?

Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(1/(1/(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))&",",","&A2&","))))*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),""))
```

Before the second TRIM, if I just add "0"& the results work but each has a 0 before it. For example:

```
))))*"0"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE
```

Results in something like 0C4321,0P0123,0P0678.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be modified as such:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))&",",","&A1&",")),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),""))
```

But there is a shorter version that does not require the named range.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[contains(',"&A2&",',concat(',', ., ','))]"))
```

Depending on one's version these may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thank you. The shorter version works great. The first one keeps failing for some reason. I keep getting "There is a problem with this formula".

Comment: @RowDogSA see edit, had the `)` in the wrong spots.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1&","&B1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=.]"))
```